# If $P(x^5)+xQ(x^5)+x^2R(x^5)=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)S(x)$ , then prove that $P(x)$ is divisible by $x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $P,Q,R,S$ are polynomials such that: $P(x^5)+xQ(x^5)+x^2R(x^5)=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)S(x)$ , then prove that $P(x)$ is divisible by $x-1$

I thought a lot on this but no result!!
By the way,one idea is to insert some values for $x$ and try to produce a system of equations for the given polynomials,but I'm not sure it works.

Comment: See here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wj3_FxnRz5kC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=if+P,+Q,+R,+S+are+polynomials+such+that+P(x%5E5)%2BxQ(x%5E5)%2Bx%5E2R(x%5E5)%3D(x%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1)S(x)&source=bl&ots=2soNihY2oV&sig=GOnCP5N-jqvpjQ_Y-JMu0fkBsHo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq67-nhbTYAhXHPo8KHdPACKYQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=if%20P%2C%20Q%2C%20R%2C%20S%20are%20polynomials%20such%20that%20P(x%5E5)%2BxQ(x%5E5)%2Bx%5E2R(x%5E5)%3D(x%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1)S(x)&f=false

Comment: This problem can be easly extended by one more polynomial:  $$P(x^5)+xQ(x^5)+x^2R(x^5)+x^3T(x^5)=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)S(x)$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly it is easy to see that the roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 =0$ are all different. Also if $a$ is a root for $ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ then $a^5=1$. The same holds for the rest of three roots: $b,c,d$.

Now if we plug in each root in
$P(x^5)+xQ(x^5)+x^2R(x^5)=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)S(x)$ 
we get:

$$P(1)+aQ(1)+a^2R(1)= 0$$
$$P(1)+bQ(1)+b^2R(1)= 0$$
$$P(1)+cQ(1)+c^2R(1)= 0$$
$$P(1)+dQ(1)+d^2R(1)= 0$$

So quadratic function $f(x) = P(1)+xQ(1)+x^2R(1)$ has 4 different roots and so $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, so $P(1)=Q(1)=R(1)=0$ and thus the conclusion.

Comment: Would you please explain how can we check all of the roots of that polynomial are different?

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi Divide $x^4+...+1=0$ with $x^2$ and make a substitution $t=x+1/x$. You get $t^2+t-10$ which is easy to solve....

Comment: How can a quadratic function have 4 different roots

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega$ be a primitive fifth root of unity.

Plugging in $\omega, \omega^2, \cdots,\omega^4$ in the equations successively we get that $P(1)+xQ(1)+x^2 R(1) = 0$ for four distinct complex numbers. Hence it must be identically $0$

So $P(1)=Q(1)=R(1)= 0$

Thus $P(x), Q(x), R(x) $ are all divisible by $(x-1)$

Comment: I now  realize that this is pretty much the same solution as John Watson's.